# Qt push button event using Qt Designer not working: "No such slot QApplication"

Tags: c++, qt, events, button, designer

I've read several articles about push button events in Qt but none seem to solve my problem. I have a simple GUI built with Qt Designer which only contains one button. The run-time error I get is the following:

Object::connect: No such slot QApplication::FullSizeR() in CameraWindow.h:25
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'FullSize')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'CameraViewer')

FullSizeR() is the function I want called when My button is pushed.

Here's' how main is defined:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
// initialize resources, if needed
// Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

QApplication app(argc, argv);
CameraWindow cw;
cw.show();
//app.setActiveWindow(&cw);
//cw.getData();       // this paints the window  
return app.exec();
}
```

And this is how CameraWindow is defined:

```
class CameraWindow : public QDialog{
Q_OBJECT
public:
bool serverConnected;
void getData();
CameraWindow()
{
    widget.setupUi(this); //this calls Qt Designer code
    //the function bellow produces a run-time error
    //access the button via widget.FullSize
    connect(widget.FullSize,SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(FullSizeR()));
}
QLabel *imgl;
virtual ~CameraWindow();
protected slots:
    void FullSizeR();
private:
    Ui::CameraWindow widget;
};
```

I've properly included QObject and my function definition under 'slots'
This is the definition of FullSizeR:

```
void CameraWindow::FullSizeR()
{
   QMessageBox::information(this,"Button clicked!\n", "Warning");
}
```

The above doesn't seem to be hard to solve. I know its something simple if I only knew Qt a bit better :-/

Thanks All

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
connect(widget.FullSize,SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(FullSizeR()));
```

The error message says it all: `qApp` doesn't have the slot. You need `this`:

```
connect(widget.FullSize, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(FullSizeR()));
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! It had to be something simple as that. It wasn't apparent that QApplication was referring to QApp but now it makes sense.

Comment: @roboto1986: me too did this kind of mistakes at the early days. :)